# PHP Loop do some once the loop as finished

Tags: php, foreach, loops

I have this PHP loop,

```
foreach($returnedContent as $k => $v) {
    $imageName = str_replace($replaceData, "", $v['contentImageName']);
    echo "<a class='contentLink' href='".base_url()."welcome/getFullContent/$v[contentId]'>";
    echo "<img src='/media/uploads/".strtolower($v['categoryTitle'])."/".$imageName."_thumb.png' alt='$v[contentTitle]' />";
    echo "</a>";
}
```

Once the lopp has finished I was hoping it would be possible to do loop to print x amount of grey boxes is this possible and if so how, basically if the first loop returns 1 item i need the second loop to print out 11 boxes, if the first one returns 9 items I need the second loop to return 3 boxes.

Make sense? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

So if you want a total of 12 boxes, set a counter and decrement:

```
$boxes = 12;
foreach($returnedContent as $k =>$v){
   // all your previous stuff
   $boxes--;
}

for($i = 0; $i < $boxes; $i++){
   // print your box here
}
```

Depending on your application you may also want to check that the number of items in $returnContent is <= $boxes.  If it is greater than $boxes you won't get an error but you will get rows with more than $boxes images.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep a counter and increment it for each loop iteration, then add

```
for (;$counter < 11; ++$counter) {
    do_loop_stuff();
}
```

Comment: I would use `count($returnedContent)` instead of variable. Also, is it really possible to start a for loop with a `;`? I've never seen this.

Comment: @Robin, I bet you haven't seen `for(;;)`, which is also quite legal :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do something like this (assuming $`returnedContent` is numerically indexed):

```
//count to 12 so we get 12 items
for ($i=0; $i<12; $i++) {
    //check if there is an entry to print
    if (isset($returnedContent[$i])) {
        $v = $returnedContent[$i];
        $imageName = str_replace($replaceData, "", $v['contentImageName']);
        echo "<a class='contentLink' href='".base_url()."welcome/getFullContent/$v[contentId]'>";
        echo "<img src='/media/uploads/".strtolower($v['categoryTitle'])."/".$imageName."_thumb.png' alt='$v[contentTitle]' />";
        echo "</a>";
    } else {
        //draw grey box
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After the first loop, you can do:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 12 - count($returnedContent); $i++)
{
 // print the grey boxes.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm Im not sure Im understanding you but

```
$c = count($returnedContent);
```

will get you the amount of items in the variable

then:

```
$c = (11-$c);
if($c > 0) {
    for($i=0;$i<$c;$i++) {
      // print gray box
    }
}
```

after the first loop. You could also use a counter variable inside the first loop.

Answer (score 0):

I did interpret the question as "Do something when the loop has finished iterating".
In which case a for/foreach loop isn't the best choice here.
how about

```
<?php
$i = 0;
do {
    echo $i;
} while ($i > 0);
//then do whatever else you need to.
?>
```